# Why this actionEvent on a Java Swing menu item does not work?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have created a basic JFrame using NetBeans form designer. I have reduced it to just a couple of menu items.

I intend to do something when user clicks on "Open", my understanding is that I have to add an "actionPerformed" through a listener, which can be done using NetBeans Designer.

[image]

```
    private void jMenu3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        System.out.println("ACTION PERFORMED");
    }
```

But when I click on "Open" nothing happens I can not see the output message.

This is my main routine:

```java
package test.dbviewer;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SealionDBViewer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {

        UIManager.setLookAndFeel ("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
        JFrame databaseViewer = new DatabaseViewer();
        databaseViewer.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

This is the reproducible code that NetBeans generate:

```java
package test.dbviewer;


public class DatabaseViewer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form DatabaseViewer
     */
    public DatabaseViewer() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jSplitPane1 = new javax.swing.JSplitPane();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuBar2 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu3 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu4 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        jMenuItem1.setText("jMenuItem1");

        jMenuItem2.setText("jMenuItem2");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jMenu3.setText("Open");
        jMenu3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenu3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenuBar2.add(jMenu3);

        jMenu4.setText("Exit");
        jMenuBar2.add(jMenu4);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 267, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jMenu3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        System.out.println("ACTION PERFORMED");
    }                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DatabaseViewer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DatabaseViewer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DatabaseViewer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(DatabaseViewer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DatabaseViewer().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu4;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    private javax.swing.JSplitPane jSplitPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: not sure if this is your actual problem , but I guess the "Open" item should be a [JMenuItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html) and not a `JMenu`

Comment: Thanks, apparently you can not have jMenuItem as jMenuBar child,  which means I could not have a jMenuBar with just top level menu items. With jMenuItem under the jMenu it works

Comment: yes, this is the way they work

Comment: Thanks, it is clear how it works now.